# Programming and Data structure

Tags: data-structures

Suppose you are given arrays p [1......N]  and q [1......N] both uninitialized, that is, each location may contain an arbitrary value), and a variable count, initialized to 0. Consider the following procedures set and is_set:

```
set(i) { 
    count = count + 1; 
    q[count] = i; 
    p[i] = count; 
} 
is_set(i) {
    if (p[i] ≤ 0 or p[i] > count)
        return false; 
    if (q[p[i]] ≠ i)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Show that if set(i) has not been called for some i, then regardless of what p[i] contains, is_set(i) will return false.

My reasoning:-is_set(i)
If p[i] is <=0 then first condition of OR is  true and first if is executed . If p[i]>0 ,then we know count is zero and hence second condition in OR of first if will be true.SO whatever p[i] may contain it will always enter in this if and return false.Please correct me if wrong

Comment: If `i` hasn't been set, `p[i]` might contain any possible value, probably under 0 or over `count`, BUT there's a chance that it contains a possible value between those two. So if it does, we need to check the second if statement. `p[i]` contains the position in the order you've set `i`, so of course, `q[p[i]]` should be equal to `i`, because `q[]` is the array storing the values of `i` ordered in time. So, if `i` had not been set, `p[i]` would be storing the position of a different number, so `q[p[i]]` would return a number different than `i` that would have already been set in that position

Comment: What exactly does '`set(i)` has not been called for some `i`' mean? Does it mean 'for each `i` there was no call to `set(i)`' or does it mean 'there is an `i` for which `set(i)` has not been called'?

Comment: The only mistake in your reasoning is that you assume that an arbitrary value will be out of the bounds you have, but an arbitrary value is, indeed, believe it or not, arbitrary, so it could actually be between those bounds. Of course, the chances are extremely low if you have a small N, but let's say `N = 2000000000`, which is closer to the maximum integer value. What are the chances now? You need to consider every possibility

Comment: @Codor to be honest that's easily understandable. You call `set(1)`, `set(2)`, `set(3)` and `set(5)`. Has `set(i)` not been called for some `i`? Yes, for `i = 4`, for example, or `i = 6`, or `i = 1000000`...